# Do I have a 3G modem on my Lenovo x201?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, 3g

After reinstalling Windows 7 on my computer I noticed that I had to install drivers for Qualcomm Gobi 2000. As far as I know, this is a 3G modem.

I found a SIM-card slot under my battery, and after inserting a sim-card it popped up "Verizon Wireless" (I do not have verizon) under mobile connections in the sys tray. But, I can't connect...

The computer is a Lenovo X201 - 3680-M89

So, do I actually have a 3G modem on this computer? And can I use it with other SIM than verizon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do have the Qualcomm Gobi 2000 3G modem. The reason it didn't work was that I had to activate the SIM-card with my mobile operator. I also installed the Lenovo Access Connections to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

> So, do I actually have a 3G modem on this computer?

Yes.

> And can I use it with other SIM than verizon?

[updated]

Maybe.

Some 3G capable laptops and other devices are "locked" to a specific network carrier. If the 3G is locked you can sometimes overcome the lock by installing generic drivers instead of the manufacturer-supplied drivers for the 3G chipset.

From paradroid's comment it seems likely that the 3G is unlocked and that you should be able to use it with any carrier's SIM (after activation and selection of a suitable data tariff)

Comment: The Gobi 2000 WWAN/GPS card in my ThinkPad X200s was carrier unlocked.